# Is there a design pattern or abstraction suited for defining messaging behaviour in socket communication?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, client-server, ipc

I've been working on a Cards Against Humanity type game in which there are several, well defined message-sending patterns between clients and the server:

The server waits for the prompts & answers to be generated, then sends them over to the client.

The clients wait for the prompts to be received, then everyone besides the czar chooses their answer(s) and sends them to the server.

The server waits for the answers to be received and sends them back to everyone.

And so on.

However I've noticed that I have a bunch of super long functions that behave sort of similarly in that they receive some data, modify some state and notify other users through sockets, a lot of boilerplate basically.

So the pattern that I noticed here is:

- someone waits for something to happen (so you need a synchronization mechanism, I used `std::condition_variable`s)
- do something (generate some data/prompt the user for input)
- send stuff over to other participants

I thought of defining a class that basically has those 3 components - a condition variable, an `std::function` that modifies stuff, and a list of sockets to notify and the data to send them. I'm not really aware of any networking-application design patterns - is there an abstraction that fits what I've described in any way?

Comment: Are you using multiple threads, e.g. one thread per client?  The use of `std::condition_variable` suggests that you are.  If so, how do you plan to respond to network events (e.g. a client disconnecting from the server) while its thread is blocked on the condition_variable ?

Comment: I've got 2 threads/client, one for receiving and one for sending data. As for disconnects, as far as I know they're signaled by `recv` returning 0. (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html). I've written a wrapper class for the classic C style sockets in which I'm handling that case.

Comment: I've found the threads+blockingI/O approach to be problematic, since any time a thread is blocked (either in `recv()` or `send()` or waiting on a condition variable) you lose control over that thread; all you can do is hope it will unblock when you need it to, and if it doesn't, you're stuck.  That makes things like quitting the program cleanly difficult to do.  My solution was to use non-blocking I/O (and do my blocking inside a central select() or poll call() instead).  That way you only need a single thread (although it will work with multiple threads as well)